# Unable to get Gulp properly installed

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, gulp

I am unable to install Gulp the right way, the `package.lock.json` file will not be created, the `node_modules/` file will be created within a file named `node_modules\gulp` and outside of such file, 3 other files will be created. See image below. I am lost and not sure how to resolve this. I appreciate any help anyone may provide.
[missing package.lock.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yC8N.png)